# Auto-save files when publishing JBoss

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss-eap-6

Eclipse already struggles to run JBoss as is, let alone if I forget to save something before I publish. Is there a way I can have it save my workspace and build it before publishing? If I let it go, its a minute to build, and if I cancel, it's at least a minute to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

you have the following option to tell eclipse what to do if you have *dirty* editors: `window > preferences > Run/Debug > Launching` > **Save required dirty editors before launching**; from eclipse's docs:

This option controls whether the user will be prompted to save any dirty editors before an application is launched. The allowable settings are:

1. Always - when this option is selected, the user is never prompted to save dirty editors, and editors are automatically saved.
2. Never - when this option is selected, the user is never prompted to save dirty editors, and editors are not automatically saved.
3. Prompt - when this option is selected, the user is prompted to save dirty editors before launching an application.

So if you already have `build automatically` checked you can either choose `Always` or `Prompt`

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but thanks for the advice. When running on my local server, I don't ever utilize `Run on Server`, rather `JBoss Server > Deployment > Full Publish` to deploy an updated version of my code.